# Dynamic ColumnName in EF Core using FormattableString c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to write raw SQL with `FormattableString` with a dynamic column name?

```cs
FormattableString query = @$"UPDATE table1 SET {dynamicColumnName} = {dynamicColumnName} + 1";
```

The problem here it doesn't work and I get an error at

```
Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(query);
```

I think EF Core treats `FormattableString` in a way that considers an interpolated as a parameter, resulting in `@p0,@p1` for each `{dynamicColumnName}`.

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: I would not recommend to use formattable strings for update query composing. Read [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Show full code. How do you use this string?

Comment: @Gleb, You are right, but I think validating the input before adding it in that query may help.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Nothing is special just normal like this, ```await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(query);```, I could ignore that problem in another case I had,  but currently I am stuck :) , I will try to do it in another way.

Comment: You can't do this since each parameter you pass in will be used as a SQL parameter, and you can't parameterise table names.

Comment: Also as @Gleb said, this is highly dangerous and "validating the input" as you suggest is extremely difficult.

Comment: @DavidG , I will find another solution then, Thanks.

Comment: Third party solutions is not an option?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, idk any... would you recommend me a one ?

Comment: [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` is intended to pass parameters by interpolation, not column names.
Thus, the simple solution in this case is not to use `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync`.

```
string query = @$"UPDATE table1 SET {dynamicColumnName} = {dynamicColumnName} + 1";
Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(query);
```

This results in the column names being interpolated into the string before the query is executed, thus not being used as a parameter.